# Can i use Amazon API to get products which will be able to ship in certain country?

Tags: amazon-product-api

Is it possible in Amazon API to get only the products which are listed under the `AmazonGlobal` and will be able to ship to certain countries like singapore?

From what I have seen when shopping in the AmazonGlobal section, I will not be able to tell if the product will be able to ship to my country until i add the product in my cart and click "estimate shipping rate" and then it either goes through or it shows "This item cannot be shipped to your country".

Comment: Hi. Could you find anything? Also looking to accomplish this

Comment: I think i found a solution, not ideal though